# Limit superior equals limit supremum

Tags: analysis

Let $\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim \sup _{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n}<\infty$. For each $j \in \mathbb{N}$, define $s_{j}=\sup \left\{x_{n}: n \geqslant j\right\}$. Prove that $\lim _{j \rightarrow \infty} s_{j}=\lim \sup _{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n}$ (be sure to include the $-\infty$ case).

I'm kinda confused by this question as what we have to show is also the definition of the limit superior. So, I tried to understand it using a simple example, but still don't get it.

For instance, let $x_n=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, then:

$s_1=\sup\{2, 3, 4, 5\}=5 $, $s_2=\sup\{3, 4, 5\}=5$, $s_3=\sup \{4, 5\}=5$ and $s_4=\sup\{5\}=5$. So, $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} s_j=5$ and on the other hand, $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =\sup E=5$ where $E=\{x \cup \pm \infty \mid \text{there's a subsequence } x_j, x_j \rightarrow x\}$ but this is the finite case and I don't know how to deal with all the cases!

I also read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593106/understanding-the-definitions-of-limit-superior-and-limit-inferior-of-a-real-seq) and was trying to use this definition to get it done, but not much of help!

Comment: You are right about $\lim_{j \to \infty} s_j$ traditionally being the definition of the limit supremum, so my guess is that the author of the question has defined limit supremum in some other way (just a guess, but perhaps as the smallest subsequential limit of the sequence, with the special case of $-\infty$ for when the sequence has no convergent subsequence). Where did you read the question?

Comment: @joeb It's a question in our class notes. In the class, we defined limit superior to be the supremum of the set $E$ that I introduced above which is actually the set of limit points of the sequence.

Comment: Ah yes I missed that part. In that case, let $x = \sup E$ and $y = \lim_{j \to \infty} s_j$. Here is one way to prove $x = y$. First show that $x \geqslant y$ by showing that $y \in E$ (or that a subsequence converges to $y$). Then prove the reverse inequality $x \leqslant y$ by choosing a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$ and noting that for any $j$ you have $x_{n_k} \leqslant s_j$ for all but finitely many $k$, whence $x = \lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k} \leqslant s_j$.

Comment: @joeb Thank you so much, I think I get it for the case that the sequence converges to a number and not the infities. But for the $-\infty$ case, I don't know how to do it

Comment: Well I would need to know exactly how you are defining a limit supremum of $-\infty$. How does $E$ fit in to your definition? Anyway, I do know that $\lim_{j \to \infty} s_j = - \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = -\infty$ in the sense that $(\forall \xi \in \mathbb{R})(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(n \geqslant N \Longrightarrow x_n < \xi)$.